# JAX-RS (Jersey) API in standalone Servlet 5 container does not start

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

Just want to build a Java application with a REST API (JAX-RS implemented by Jersey 2.33) that runs in a standalone Servlet 5 container, e.g. Tomcat 10. For this the build process (via Maven) creates a *.war file which is put subsequently into the *webapps/* folder to start it.

The problem is that the JAX-RS API, that is to say its servlet, is not coming up. So calling the URL

http://localhost:8080/weld/api/address

produces HTTP Status 404 (not found).

The *pom.xml* looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>weld Maven Webapp</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <servlet-api.version>5.0.0</servlet-api.version>
        <jax-rs-api.version>2.1.6</jax-rs-api.version>
        <jersey.version>2.33</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jax-rs-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>weld</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The required dependencies and the rest to get it to work I have read from the [Jersey documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e3553).
The *.war doesn't contain any *web.xml* because since Servlet API 3.1 this is optional. The class *javax.ws.rs.core.Application* which should actually auto-detected and bootstrap the JAX-RS API looks as follows:

```
package de.test.weld;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

   public MyApplication() {
       registerClasses(AddressService.class);
   }
}
```

The Java class with the very endpoint looks then like this:

```
package de.test.weld;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/address")
public class AddressService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getAddress() {
        return "any text, bla, nonsense";
    }
}
```

Anything essential seems to be missing so that the Jersey Sevlet can be started.

A glimpse into the **.war* looks like this:

```
$> jar -tvf webapps/weld.war 
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 META-INF/
   131 Sat Mar 13 13:13:22 CET 2021 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/classes/
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/classes/de/
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/classes/de/test/
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/classes/de/test/weld/
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/
   619 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/classes/de/test/weld/AddressService.class
  1025 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/classes/de/test/weld/TestServlet.class
   581 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/classes/de/test/weld/MyApplication.class
 25058 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
 19479 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar
1174508 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.33.jar
942190 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-2.33.jar
 18140 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar
253811 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jersey-client-2.33.jar
 91930 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar
 32383 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jersey-container-servlet-2.33.jar
 73402 Fri Mar 12 15:26:10 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.33.jar
140376 Fri Mar 12 15:11:24 CET 2021 WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 META-INF/maven/
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 META-INF/maven/de.test/
     0 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 META-INF/maven/de.test/weld/
  2757 Sat Mar 13 13:12:34 CET 2021 META-INF/maven/de.test/weld/pom.xml
   106 Sat Mar 13 13:13:24 CET 2021 META-INF/maven/de.test/weld/pom.properties
```

Here are some information about the versions in use:
Java 11, Maven 3.6, JAX-RS (Jersey 2.33), Servlet API 5.0.0, Tomcat 10 or Jetty 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Jersey 3.x. The 3.x line is the first line that makes use of the Jakarta namespace. You have all the Jakarta dependencies (JAX-RS, Servlet), just the Jersey version you are using does not make use of them. See the [Jersey docs](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/) for the latest 3.x version.

In the new Jakarta EE, all the `javax` packaging has changed to `jakarta`, e.g. `jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath`. Once you change the Jersey version (assuming you don't have any other old dependencies, you should get import errors. All the `javax` imports should show errors. They should all be switched out with `jakarta`. *All* the `javax` imports (that includes JAX-RS, Servlet, Inject, etc).

Comment: Yes, you did it! Many thanks for the solution. I changed the Jersey version to 3.0.1, the JAX-RS APi version to 3.0.0, changed the imports in source code accordingly and then to get it work I had also to add the dependency org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2/3.0.1